# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd"

Tags: windows, jenkins, cmd, command

I am running below code in jenkinsfile. Currently we have 1450 xml files which we send to webserver for validation with below command it runs 140 times for each xml file we have.

```
String responseFile = bat(returnStdout: true, 
    script: "curl --header \"Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8\"
    --header \"MAXAUTH: ${env_auth['envname']}\" 
    --header \"SOAPAction:urn:processDocument\" --data-binary $str $url").trim()
```

It works fine sometime but failing with below error most of the time.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in 
directory "c:\directory_name"): CreateProcess error=5, 
Access is denied
```

Could you guys please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the command prompt in Jenkins, including the command in% PATH%. On the folder, you need to give write and execute permission to the user who is running jenkins.